# Выделение чисел из массива

Tags: java

Задан массив элементов:
String[] str = {"одежда", "комар", "90", "Саша", "75"};
Как выделить числа из массива?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Можно так:**

```
import java.util.regex.Matcher;
import java.util.regex.Pattern;

public class regex {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        String[] str = {"одежда", "комар", "90", "Саша", "75"};
        for(String s: str){
            if(isNumber(s)) System.out.println(s);
        }

    }

    public static boolean isNumber(String str){
        Pattern p = Pattern.compile("(^0$)|(^[1-9]([0-9])*)$");
        Matcher m = p.matcher(str);
        return m.find();
    }
}
```

Вывод:

90

75

**Или так:**

```
public class regex {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        String[] str = {"одежда", "комар", "90", "Саша", "75"};
        for(String s: str){
            if(isNumber(s)) System.out.println(s);
        }

    }

    public static boolean isNumber(String str) {
        try {
            double d = Double.parseDouble(str);
        } catch (NumberFormatException nfe) {
            return false;
        }
        return true;
    }
}
```

Вывод тот же.

Answer (score 0):

Попробуйте распознать в строке **Integer**, если не получится - значит не число.

```
public static boolean isNumber(String str)  
{  
   try  
   {  
      Integer.parseInt(str);  
      return true;  
   }  
   catch(Exception e)  
   {  
      return false;  
   }  
}
```

Ну и провести проверку для каждого элемента массива:

```
for (String item: str)
   if (isNumber(item)) ... // Например записываем в новый массив
```

Если могут встречаться не только целые числа, то меняем Integer на Double.

Comment: Мне вариант с регулярками больше нравится )